# Не срабатывает событие hide в модальном окне bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Пытаюсь привязать элементарную функцию на открытие или закрытие модального окна бутстрапа:

```
$('#load_new_file_ok2').on('show', function () {
  alert('sss');
})
```

так же пробую и с `hide`. Но реакции никакой, смотрю через инспектор - события привязаны, но не срабатывают, отладчик тоже пустой.

Comment: а к чему привязываете то?

Comment: К модальному окну 
<div id="load_new_file_ok2" class="modal fade">

Comment: не сразу понял :) думал вам закрыть надо, удалил свой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вот это попробуйте

```
$('#load_new_file_ok2').on('shown', function () {
  alert('sss');
});
```

не `on('show'`, а `on('shown'`.

А для Bootstrap 3 попробуйте так:

```
$('#load_new_file_ok2').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  alert('sss');
})
```

Comment: да с shown опечатка, но результат тот же, hide тоже не работает.